# Is it possible draw into the camera view

Tags: android, camera

is it possible to draw into the camera view? For example, like barcode readers have a line that reads the barcode. And if it is, is there anywhere some samples that I can read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw over it like you would any other view try something where you put the camera view inside of a `RelativeLayout` having it fill the entire layout and then placing your items inside of the `RelativeLayout` along with it.

Comment: I think I found code example how to do it - http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/drawing-on-camera-preview-t4609.html